# Unreadable Offline DB files of ACRCloud Music Recognition SDK

Tags: ios, asp.net-web-api, voice-recognition, audio-fingerprinting, shazam

Pls help,

I'm using ACRCloud's Music Recognition iOS SDK for offline recognition in movie theatre like Shazam. After uploading audio files and downloaded the Offline DB file, I got this error:

```
{“status”:{“msg”:”init error: Offline DB files are unreadable!”,”version”:1.0”,”code”:2001}}
```

How can I solve this problem, Im beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACRCloud Engine requires absolute directory of Offline DB. If Offline DB files is in your project of APK, you can access those files by InputStream. So you must copy those file to SD cards (or other path) where Engine can access, before Engine initialization with "initWithConfig of ACRCloudClient".